# error: no matching function for call to ‘Complex::Complex()’

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I just started with function overloading and i am stuck with the following code:

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class Complex
{
double real; 
double img; 

public: 
    Complex(double r, double i)
    {
        real = r; 
        img = i; 
    }
    
    void display()
    {
        cout<<real<<" + i"<<img<<endl; 
    }
    
    Complex operator+(Complex c)
    {
        Complex temp; 
        temp.real = real + c.real; 
        temp.img = img + c.img; 
        return temp;
    }
    
    Complex operator-(Complex c)
    {
        Complex temp; 
        temp.real = real - c.real; 
        temp.img = img - c.img; 
        return temp;
    }
    }; 

    int main()
    {
    Complex c1(23.89, -42.98), c2(54.23, 53.35); 

    cout<<"Adding the two complex numbers: "<<endl;
    Complex c3 = c1 + c2; 
    c3.display();

    cout<<"Subtracting two complex numbers: "<<endl; 
    Complex c4 = c1 - c2; 
    c4.display();

    return 0;
    }
```

The error for both the operator overloading functions is :

no matching function for call to ‘Complex::Complex()’
Complex temp;
^~~~

Comment: `Complex temp;` will call the default constructor. You don't have a default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

And indeed there is no `Complex::Complex()`.

In this code

```
    Complex temp; 
    temp.real = real + c.real; 
    temp.img = img + c.img;
    return temp;
```

how do you think `temp` is being constructed? The compiler is looking for `Complex::Complex()` and when it doesn't find it that's an error.

You could add `Complex::Complex()` but the simpler fix is to use the constructor you have already written

```
    Complex temp(real + c.real, img + c.img);
    return temp;
```

Or even simpler, get rid of `temp` completely

```
    return Complex(real + c.real, img + c.img);
```

Answer (score 0):

The class does not have the default constructor used in declarations like this

```
Complex temp;
```

You could declare it for example like

```
explicit Complex() : real( 0.0 ), img( 0.0 )
{
}
```

The operators should be declared at least like

```
Complex operator+( const Complex &c ) const;
```

and

```
Complex operator-( const Complex &c ) const;
```

They do not change the left operand.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have defined only one constructor. So, the statment `Complex temp;` is failing. You have to define another constructor without any argument.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer